# C# Udp client fragmented packet

Tags: c#, sockets

How do I receive a fragmented packet using the udpclient class?

The servers response is too large and is split up into two packets. I can confirm both packets are received by wireshark.

I'm only getting the first packet from the udpclient.Receive method.  If I try to running the udpclient.Receive method a second time I don't get the second half of the message.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code, calling `Receive()` twice you should be able to get them all (AFAIK) then there should be something else. Oh, note that if a packet arrives while you're processing the first one...then it's gone forever. You probably need to go with `BeginReceive()` and call it again just after `EndReceive()`, as early as possible and for sure before you perform any processing. Yes, that's UPD...

Comment: _1)_ I sounds like a bad practice splitting up a message in 2 udp datagrams. The whole idea of udp is sending non dependend datagrams. Why doesn't TCP fit? 
_2)_ When receiving udp messages, you should store the datagrams in a list and handle it on another thread. If the decoding takes too long, you'll might mis the next one.